# I believe my ex has an enterprise account. We live together and share itunes.

Tags: enterprise

What information from my Iphone 5 can he access with enterprise account and itunes? I do not back up my phone because of this worry. Yes I understand I can get a different ituness account but I am temporarily disabled and rely on him and don't want to anger him. Please just tell me what he can access and how if possible I can have some privacy on my phone. Also, if I restore my phone does is "clean" my phone of any tokens, etc (have seen this word in my email configuration on iphone and I can't change anything in that screen)? I don't even have the option of password encrypting my Iphone backup in my Itunes. 
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is an "enterprise account?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you're living with someone else, you are at their mercy whatever you do, you'll never be 100% safe. So just forget about it.

Comment: @Lohoris you may be right about never being 100% safe where access to a device is possible. But to just say forget about it when you do not even know what the OP is asking is a bit off. There are always measures people can take to drop the 100% un safe to a lower number.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise tracking relies on profiles that are always visible to the end user in the settings app.

To remove that ability to track location, remote wipe and do other sorts of reporting you can try to delete the profiles.

- tap the settings app
- tap general
- swipe up and at the bottom is where profiles will be displayed
- tap profiles and delete any that you do not want / approve of

Each profile will tell you generally what it does. If you have a profile that cannot be removed, you can wipe the device and see if restoring your backup has cleared the profile. Worst case, sync off the data you need through iTunes or iCloud and then erase all content and settings on the device. When you set the device up new, here will be no enterprise ties, no profiles and you can build up your phone as you wish.